# Python: Using binary search to perform natural sorting

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-search, natural-sort

I am using a binary search to insert into a sorted list of lists. The code below works fine for an alphanumeric sort but I cannot figure out how to make the sort work in a natural sorting order.

The key "name" will contain a mixture of numerical values and Words and currently sorts alphabetically resulting in the numbers being in string rather than numeric order.

Is it possible to insert into a list of lists in natural order?

For example if I want to insert the following lists

```
{ "Orange", "Frog" 3, 4, 55}
{ 3031, "Bob", 21, 4, 56 }
{ 400, "Tree", 6, 66, 75}
```

I would like the order to end up as

```
{ 400, "Tree", 6, 66, 75}
{ 3031, "Bob", 21, 4, 56 }
{ "Orange", "Frog", 3, 4, 55}
```

My code is as follows:

```
def binSearch(listSearch, name):
low = 0  
high = len(listSearch) 
mid = 0

while low < high:  
    # for get integer result   
    mid = (high + low) // 2  

    # Check if name is present at mid   
    if listSearch[mid].name < name:
        low = mid + 1 
    else:
        high=mid
```

This results in

```
{ 3031, "Bob", 21, 4, 56 }
{ 400, "Tree", 6, 66, 75}
{ "Orange", "Frog", 3, 4, 55 }
```

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: your example data with `{}` can suggest that you keep them as `set()` but `set()` doesn't have to respect order. If you keep it as lists then show it as `[ ]` instead of `{ }`

Comment: You are mixing many things here...  if you are using binary search, then the list you are searching needs to be *already sorted*.  So is your question is on how to sort the list *alphabetically* (which is what you have displayed)?  And I'm assuming you mis-used the set notation and intended lists or tuples.

Comment: My question and description may not be clear. My code uses a list of lists. Which currently uses a binary search to ensure each new entry is added in the correct place. This works fine but the element I am using as the key (a name) can be numeric or alphabetic in value. The end result is that the list is sorted correctly according to my logic - but numbers are dealt with as strings. My python is limited and the type of sorting I actually need is natural sorting. My example was merely showing the difference between alphanumeric and natural sorting

Comment: I don't think Python has a built-in function or comparison operator for natural sorting, but here is a package that does: https://github.com/SethMMorton/natsort